# I deleted all the contents of /boot and now server is not booting

Tags: centos7, filesystems, boot, grub2, boot-loader

I did something stupid. My thinking was that /boot directory is empty and contents come to /boot each time the computer starts. My /boot drive was giving me error messages no space left so I thought there might be junk files.
I deleted all the contents of /boot by `rm -rf *` and rebooted the computer by `reboot` command.
Now the system is not starting. I am getting error at boot i.e. 
`error file /grub2/i386-pc/normal.mod not found` 
`Entering rescue mode ...`
`grub rescue>`

Most of the search shows solving the issue by repairing the grub. In my case I know that I have deleted the contents so how could I restore the system.
I am using Centos 7.

Answer (score 6):

The /boot partition holds important Linux kernel files as well as Grub files. Without them, your system will not boot (as you already figured out). And just restoring the Grub files is not going to help. To recover from this you should be able to do the following:

- Boot the system into rescue mode from the CentOS DVD/ISO image
- Reinstall the kernel by running `yum reinstall kernel`
- Reinstall Grub by running `/sbin/grub2-install /dev/sda`

In the last step, you might need to replace `/dev/sda` with another device name, depending on your hardware. It should be your primary hard drive from which you want to boot. On virtual machines, this is usually `/dev/vda`. If you are unsure, you can use the `lsblk` command (you may need to run `yum install util-linux` first) to list all your block devices and you should be able to recognize the disk by it's size.

After this, your system should boot normally again.

Comment: This sounds good. I am making a centos 7 usb to boot and do the process. I will update.

Comment: Till now its not going very well for me. Now I am backing up the data by using the live usb and network.

Comment: Okay I tried my best but failed. I tried both live and bootable centos 7 but no luck.
I dont have internet in rescue mode of bootable where I can use yum. I dont get /mnt/sysimage when boot from live cd so I can install grub or kernel. Is there any application in Centos like boot-repair in Ubuntu https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i97y5Y2nChs

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently. I could recover by following the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1234860/accidentally-deleted-boot-partition).
I documented the steps that I followed in a new answer.

I copying my answer here for convenience:

I have a Fedora 30 PC. The boot partition is on `/dev/sda3`
and the root partition is on an LVLM named `Fedora-root`. 
I ran all commands with the root account.

1. I booted from  the Fedora live media (from a USB drive)
2. Mount my root partition

   ```
   mount /dev/mapper/Fedora-root /mnt
   ```
3. Mount my boot partition

   ```
   mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/boot
   ```
4. Copy the kernel from the live partition to the intended boot partition

   ```
   cp /boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r) /mnt/boot/
   ```
5. Mount system partitions

   ```
   mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
   mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
   mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
   ```
6. Change root to `/mnt`

   ```
   chroot /mnt
   ```
7. Generate the `initramfs`

   ```
   dracut /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r) -v
   ```
8. Re-install grub and re-configure it

   ```
   grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
   ```

For some reason which I don't know, generating the `initramfs` was very slow and couldn't finish on my system (step 6). However, the command worked normally when I didn't chroot the filesystem. So, I skipped the steps from 3 onwards. I also had to modify the `dracut` configuration to point to the root system.

So, the new steps are:

3. Point to the root location in the `dracut` configuration

   ```
   echo "root=/dev/mapper/Fedora/root" > /etc/dracut.conf.d/kernel.conf
   ```
4. Re-install the `kernel` and generate the `initramfs`

   ```
   dracut /dev/sda/initramfs-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r) -v
   ```
5. I then followed steps 3-6 above, so I can rebuild the grub configuration (this step may be not needed, I was over cautious)

   ```
   mount /dev/mapper/Fedora-root /mnt`  
   mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/boot
   cp /boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r) /mnt/boot/
   mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
   mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
   mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
   chroot /mnt
   ```
6. Re-install grub and re-configure it

   ```
   grub2-install /dev/sda
   grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
   ```

**Note for NVIDIA owners**
I have a NVIDIA GPU, and I had the proprietary drivers installed before the incident.
The restored kernel from the live media used the Nouveau drivers (as it is the default driver in Fedora). The restored kernel was also not the latest version. When I updated the `kernel` afterwards using the GUI interface, it used the NVIDIA proprietary drivers.